# Thermostat Does Not Control A/C or Heat

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning, furnace

We have two thermostats in our house - one upstairs and one in the middle level. We are having issues with the thermostat in the middle level and have noticed the following:

1. We can turn on the fan with the middle thermostat but the fan continues to run even when we try to turn it off. The only way to turn it off is to flip the breaker.
2. The heat does not work in the middle level.
3. The air conditioning does not work in the middle level.
4. We can run the heat in the top level (through the thermostat upstairs) but I believe there is a separate furnace in the attic.
5. The air conditioner works in the top level and we only have one air conditioning unit outside.

What is the best way to fix this? I'm assuming that it's a problem with the middle thermostat or wiring since it's the root of all the issues. The A/C works while controlled by the upstairs thermostat but not while controlled by the middle level thermostat.

We have the HX thermostat (https://www.johnsoncontrols.com/residential-and-smart-home/hx3-thermostat)

Comment: I would suggest you get a HVAC tech to check the system and explain what you have.

Comment: Hello - there is a separate furnace in the attic.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to determine if you have two separate systems.

For AC just see if you have two condensors... the big square things (almost always gray or beige) outside your house with fans on top. Could be on the roof but generally not. Looks something like this[image]

Sounds like your house is larger, In that case it is not uncommon to have two separate systems. Like you said one furnace might be in the attic or an upstairs equipment room while the other is typically basement or floor level as is typical.

If all else fails turn off one thermostat and then turn on the other to full heat, then to full cool walk around and verify where heating or cooling is happening. Turn off the first and repeat with the second. That should at least take the guesswork out of it.

the problem is that to go any further you need to be relatively handy and comfortable working on electrical (low voltage) Your thermostat and climate control system isn't rocket science but it is advanced enough it has a few possible configurations we cannot know without some checks being made.

Essentially you can tell the system to heat or cool manually. The fact you have to open a breaker isn't as helpful as it would be in a simpler system because your thermostat gets power from your furnace... so either could be locking up, and cutting power resets both so...

Comment: Thanks a lot - we have one furnace in the attic (controlled by upstairs thermostat) and one in the basement (controlled by middle thermostat). We have one AC condensor outside and this is used by the middle thermostat and upstairs thermostat. Everything on the upstairs thermostat works properly (heat and AC). However, nothing works on the middle level thermostat (AC and heat do not work). We can use the middle thermostat to turn on the fan but it will not turn off once started.

Comment: Yeah I misread some of your post sorry. If your comfortable with a meter and some easy wiring inspections, I can talk you through it. Either your thermostat is bad or your furnace control is bad.

I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I have a multimeter handy and am comfortable with wiring. What would you recommend checking?

Comment: If you get me the furnace info for the unit controlled by the middle thermostat I can let you know. I can give you a step by step with IF/THEn to avoid the back and forth waiting

Comment: The model number of the furnace is tp9c100c20mp12cb. Please let me know if you need any additional information and I can get it for you.

Comment: weird... I only find a link to a parts diagram that doesn't show any schematics when I search it. Are you able to remove a panel and take a pic of the schematic? Or take a pic of the data plate and post that?

Answer (score 0):

Thermostat is a very simple device to control temperature (Thermo-) to be static (-stat). It used to be a bimetal strip that bends according to the temperature. It was either opening cold, to keep temperature low (for fridges etc.) or opening hot to keep temperature high (for heaters etc.)

Modern thermostats can be PID controllers that can regulate the power output more precisely than on or off.

What is kept from the old times it some rule of thumb: one heater/chiller can be regulated by one thermostat. But one thermostat can regulate multiple units. Unless there is defined hierarchy among the thermostat units.

The unit here can be radiator valve or chiller vent.

Your problem might be in the hierarchy - the upstairs themostat overrides the middle one.

Your problem might be in the mixed signals from both thermostats - they both send sighals to the units and who knows how they are resolved there.

This is very hard to resolve from the keyboard. Try to look up the manufacturers (heater, chiller, thermostats) FAQ. If you have idea who was setting the controls up try to ask them as well.

Comment: I tested out the hierarchy by turning off the top thermostat and setting the middle thermostat to cool. The A/C condenser turned off as soon as I did this and it only works when controlled by the top thermostat.

Comment: I cannot see the protocol the thermostat(s) communicate with the A/C unit(s) and heater unit(s).
It seems that the units are paired with (or wired to) only the upper thermostat. In other words, the middle one serves as a decoration now.

Really, reverse enginnering the design is very close to imposible for us.